# Why doesn't -whatif parameter get passed to pipeline

Tags: powershell, logging

Utilizing the common parameter `-Whatif` within a Powershell script e.g.:

```
Remove-Item -Path "$now\$basename" -Recurse -Whatif -Force |
    Write-Entry -Line $(get-linenumber) -level 'Info' | 
    Create-Log -title "$title.log" -display
```

The log file is blank even though I can clearly see the text onscreen. I would like to pass the `-Whatif` string to a text file. I know this has something to do with redirection but that's as far as I have gotten.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the `-Whatif` processing bypasses the standard streams for output and goes to the console directly. [This TechNet question about accessing the `-WhatIf` output from C#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e9394e83-71d9-4d7f-a5e3-8c18b2797cbd/accessing-powershell-whatif-streamoutput-data-from-net?forum=winserverpowershell) explains.

Comment: Is there way to capture the output displayed on screen.

Comment: @extraordinare - Only if you rewrite the console handler, so take that as a "not really".

Comment: Interestingly enough, while you can't redirect this output, it *is* captured by `Start-Transcript`. I'm not sure how logging is facilitated by this cmdlet, but it seems there must be *some* method to scrape the console output directly.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest - It wouldn't surprise me if `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` actually replaced the console handler (or used a [most likely undocumented] hook into it) to be able to capture output to the console (or to [notional] streams that haven't yet had redirection implemented).

Comment: It's probably something I'll take a look at the Core source to figure out; I'm intrigued now. I'm wondering if rather than scrape console output there is a Logger sort of class in .NET i'm not familiar with. This could enact such a logger, and .NET logs the activity on its own, whereas the cmdlet just triggers the process.